# Trying to find the sum of checked values in a table using react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This function currently returns the total score, but I trying to get only the sum of the checked value (score). So, each time the user selects the checkbox, the function will return the sum of the score.

"Score" is one of the three columns in a table. I am using checkboxes to select.

```
calculateTotal=(e)=> {
    const { input, checked, type} = e.target;
    let sumVal= 0;

    this.props.items.forEach((item, i)=> {
      if(checked === true){
        ( sumVal += item.score)
      }
    })

   this.setState(sumVal => sumVal)

    console.log(sumVal);
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Sum Value =" + sumVal;
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Can you provide a more concrete [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and include specific details about what isn't working as expected. What is `this.props.items`, are those the checkboxes? This implementation will either sum to the length of `items` if `checked` of the event is true, or 0 if false.

Comment: this.props.items is the data holding the score and other information (fname, lname).  And yes, this implements the sum of the length of the items. So, if a user checks 2 checkboxes it'll return the sum of all the score, instead of just the sum of those 2 checked scores.

Comment: That is what I said, that depending on the value of `e.target.checked` the function will either sum all the `item.score`'s there are, or none. Please include all relevant code. What/where are the checkboxes you refer to? How do checkboxes and `items` relate?

Answer (score 0):

When you give function in this.setState, function gets previous state as parameter. You are essentially returning same state and thus nothing is changed.

```js
calculateTotal=(e)=> {
    const { input, checked, type} = e.target;
    let sumVal= 0;

    this.props.items.forEach((item, i)=> {
      if(checked) sumVal += item.score
    })

   this.setState(prevState=>({...prevState, sumVal}));
   // this.setState({sumVal}) ; // also works

    console.log(sumVal);
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Sum Value =" + sumVal;
  }
```

Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Please try now, one  ')' was missing.